# Parse Server running locally has error when calling User signUp

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

Is there any reason I'm getting this error when running parse server locally, but not when hosted on Heroku? 
Status:100 Message:XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"

I have mongodb installed and running locally. I also have a .env file that contains `APP_ID` and `MASTER_KEY` that gets pulled in with dotenv locally.

Here's an abbreviated example of what I'm trying to do...

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dotenv  = require('dotenv').config({silent: true});
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var Parse = require('parse/node');

// Set up the parse server
var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || ''
});

// Set up express
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// Initialize parse so that I can use in my routes and controllers
Parse.initialize(process.env.APP_ID,'unused');
Parse.serverURL = process.env.SERVER_URI || 'http://locahost:1337/parse';

// Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('[form goes here that sends POST to "/sign-up"]');
});
app.post('/sign-up', function(req, res) {
  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.set("email", req.body.inputEmail);
  user.set("password", req.body.inputPassword);

  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
      res.status(200).send('Signup Success!');
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      res.status(200).send('Signup Failed');
    }
  });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Unable to connect to the Parse API` implies that the Parse sdk can't connect to the given serverURL. In your case it seems to be a typo: http://locahost:1337/parse should be http://localhost:1337/parse?

You should also remove the `var Parse = require('parse/node');` and the custom initialization as the parse sdk will be initialized in Parse Server and `Parse` will then be available globally. Take a look at the [usage](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) example in the readme. Your code should look something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dotenv  = require('dotenv').config({silent: true});
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

// Set up the parse server
var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URI || 'http://localhost:1337/parse'
});

// Set up express
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// Routes
app.post('/sign-up', function(req, res) {
  var user = new Parse.User(); // Parse available as a global variable
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks for the help Simon.

Comment: One more question: I'm having trouble getting User.logIn to create a session with this method. I'm able successfully log in the user, but when I navigate to other routes I have no access to the `request.user` object because I believe that is only available in cloud functions. 
In other words: if I can't use `Parse.User.current()` with parse-server, how is it possible to use `request.user` in `app.get('/route')` routes?

Comment: Good question! You have to do that manually for now. Checkout my answer here for an example implementation: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/497

Comment: Interesting, I'll give that a shot and report back.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be working. Great point about using jwt instead of making requests on every page load. I'll see if I can implement it. Thanks again!

Comment: Any luck implementing jwt? I am over my head and would greatly appreciate any help I could get.